# Как реализовать выпадающие списки-фильтры без перезагрузки

Tags: mysql, ajax, wordpress, фильтры

Приветствую. Имеется сайт на Wordpress. Необходимо сделать несколько выпадающих списков. Сейчас поля работают через Contact Form 7, но в них содержатся только города, указанные в HTML. Что не есть правильно. В первом списке должны отображаться города, а во втором - адреса филиалов в городе, который был выбран в первом поле. Насколько я понимаю должна использоваться БД сайта и AJAX-запросы. Но я в этом пока не силен, поэтому подскажите где искать инфу, или готовые решения, либо предложите свой вариант. Заранее спасибо за любую информацию.
Вот пример того, что хотелось бы получить.

[image: Пример]

Comment: я б вас послал пойти на биржу фриланса, (тут за вас код писать не будут), но почитавши профиль вижу, что вы пытаетесь разобраться. Давайте так. Для начала уточните, в каком виде у вас справочники городов и справочники филиалов. Они уже есть в базе? Кроме того, вы программировать умеете? Понимаете, что готовых плагинов вряд ли найти и придётся писать собственный код?

Comment: Самое толковое изложение ajax в WP на русском: https://wp-kama.ru/id_2018/ajax-v-wordpress.html

Comment: Ну я как раз запросил информацию по справочникам. А по поводу программирования, немного знаю PHP, JS, jQuery. Сейчас обложился книжками. Просто не хочу облажаться по срокам, поэтому решил спросить заранее.

Comment: Приветствую. Сегодня получил данные, это оказался обычный xls документ с перечнем адресов в разных городах и е-мейл, соответствующий каждому адресу. Смысл в том, что при выборе в дропдауне адреса и заполнении полей формы само письмо уходит на основной мейл, а его копия должна уходить на ящик, соответствующий физическому адресу офиса. Вопрос в том, как связать каждый адрес с мейлом и обработать это в Contact Form 7? Где-то писали что это можно реализовать с помощью кастомного поста и скрытых полей, но я не знаю как загуглить подобную реализацию. Может хотя бы в поиске поможете?

Comment: Вот так выглядит форма http://prntscr.com/fu1svo